# Calling base method from two different derived classes C#

Tags: c#, inheritance, methods, multiple-inheritance, derived-class

I am new to OOP and this question might be easy but could not find an answer to it. any help would be great!

If I have a base class A that has a method called DoAction()

```
base class A
{
    void DoAction(string s)
    {
       print s;
    }
}
```

I also have two derived classes B and C

```
derived class B : A
{
    string b = "I am in B class";
    base.DoAction(b);
}

derived class C : A
{
    string c = "I am in C class";
    base.DoAction(c);
}
```

My question is if the DoAction() method from the base class get called from both derived classes ((**at the same time**)), will my code counter any issues at run time? Or does each derived class has its own copy of the base method?

Does the same concept applied to events in the base class? I mean if I call the same event from two different derived classes at the same time.

Thank you

Comment: Clarify "at the same time", please.

Comment: I mean lets say both derived classes happened to perform two different tasks (one for each) at same time and these tasks require calling the base method

Comment: Your question comes down to difference between a class and a class instance (object). Learn more about that difference and you will be able to answer that question yourself

Answer (score 0):

As long as the code is not dependent on the same piece of data, you won't encounter any issues.

Comment: thank you for your answer. I just updated the code to perform a print task, do you mean if I have it that way I won't have any issue?

Comment: You won't have any issues. All I meant is that as long as you're not modifying data in one that the other is dependent on, potentially causing race issues, it will be fine.

In the above case, in classes B and C, the prints will happen in the order that the written code is executed. No issues.

Comment: This means it is a single method for all derived classes not each derived class has it is own copy of the base method? right. Sorry I just trying to understand the concept.

Comment: An instance of any derived class will inherit the members of its parent class. Thus, if you construct Class B, derived from Class A, then Class B will have inherited the member function DoAction() and be able to perform it independently as a member of itself.

Think of this: You make a game with base Character with a member Death(). There are children Orc and Elf. An instance of Orc can call Death(), and so can an instance of Elf, and neither care about one or the other. They just both die when each of their Death() is executed.

Comment: Thank you so much that helps a lot!

Comment: Great! Please upvote the answer if you think it helped.

Comment: I can't as I am new to stack